# How to Get Native Notifications with Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox, notify-osd

I recently upgraded to Firefox 4. There is extension in synaptic - xul-notify that can be used in Firefox 3.x to get native notifications through notify-osd but it is not working with Firefox 4. Is there a similar separate extension for Firefox 4 or some other workaround to get native notifications?

Comment: I don't have a solution, I'm afraid - although they may still update the extension before Firefox 4 is officially released. I just wanted to say thanks, because I'd never heard of this extension and find it really useful. :)

Comment: I can only assume that it'll be updated for Firefox 4 now that it's out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xul-ext-notify looks like it may have come to an end. Here is the git-hub page for the extension: https://github.com/linkinpark342/firefoxnotify

It hasn't been updated since 2009. Hopefully someone takes up the challenge to write another extension or update this one.

Answer (score 2):

Try to check the "GNotifier" extension: [https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/gnotifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/gnotifier/)